# Android: listview size

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am new to `Android development`.There are 4 `TextView` , 1 
`Button` and 1 `ListView` in my app.Each row in `ListView` contain 2 `TextView` and one `ImageView`.There are 8 to 10 rows in `ListView`.It consumes **80 t0 100 MB memory**.I think it consume more memory.I want to know the memory usage of my app's `ListView` is good or bad.

Comment: how do you get to know it is consuming 80 to 100 mb of memory ??

Comment: use ImageLoader to load your images in ListView.

Comment: Are you loading images from server? Are you aware of the concept of lazy loading in android ? You can check out the memory usage of your application using MAT Tool (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html) I don't think it would be consuming 80 to 100 MB of memory. You might be saying this by size of your application.

Comment: I check how much memory it consume in setting -> App -> Running app. I am loading image from resource folder.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are working with any of the application which leads to the more use of memory. You should use the `Lazy Loading` concept in your application and load all your images from resource folder as and when its needed.

Using the lazy loading concept your application will loads the images asynchronously without affecting the UI thread and background and make it runs smoother and faster. Loading all the images on main thread will affect the performance as well as the leads to the memory issue and will give you out of memory error. So always use Lazy Loading concept for such memory consuming applications .

Check out [Lazy Loading ListView in Android](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) which will help you.